# Blazor RemoteAuthenticatorView stuck in "Completing login..." after "No matching state found in storage" error

Tags: blazor, identityserver4, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM application and an OIDC provider implemented using IdentityServer 4. The authorization code flow is used between them to authenticate users. My users face a problem when they press the browser back button after completing a successful login and then try to re-login from the stale login URL. On the second login attempt the Blazor app gets stuck on "Completing login..." and using the debugger I can see a "No matching state found in storage" error being thrown: [image]

To be more specific the flow to replicate the problem goes like this:

1. User visits `https://localhost:3375`
2. User is not authenticated so he gets redirected to the `Authentication.razor` page (`NavigationManager.NavigateToLogin($"authentication/login");`).
3. `Authentication.razor` starts the the login process and redirects the user to the Identity Provider. `https://localhost:3371/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=...`
4. User enters credentials, submits login form and gets redirected back to `https://localhost:3375/authentication/login-callback?code=...`
5. `Authentication.razor` completes the login process successfully and redirects the user to `https://localhost:3375` (`Index.razor`).
6. Now the user presses the browser back button and goes back to the Identity Provider `https://localhost:3371/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=...`.
7. Submits login form second time and is redirected to `https://localhost:3375/authentication/login-callback?code=...`
8. `Authentication.razor` tries to process login callback but gets stuck on `Completing login...` because "No matching state found in storage" occurs.

Basically the same issue is described here: https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/940 and here for an MVC application [netcore with azure ad using oidc and the browser back button after sign in causing exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37981428/10839134).

The "No matching state found in storage" error is expected, what I want is to find a way to handle it or prevent it instead of having the user stuck on "Completing login...".